# Using Autofixture to create complex object (nHibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, autofixture

I have very complex object with parent-child and circular references.
I am using Nhibernate and Autofixture.
Is there any easy way or any framework could understand my Influent NHibernate Mapping and generate complex entity for me?

Comment: this has been covered lots, but normally with people asking in terms of Entity Framework rather than NHibernate. I suggest searching for that and/or looking for AutoFixture and circular reference on SO

Comment: We are using NHibernate. and so far we had to hand-carve the object tree with references. this is very time consuming. I think people who are using NHibernate with Autofixture must have the same issue. There might be a framework or tool will help us to generate complex object by analysing NHibernate mapping.

Comment: As I say, the chances are it's the same set of tradeoffs as are in play with EF - feel free to wait for a contextualized answer but the chances are the existing answers will provide insight as to how best to apply/not apply AutoFixture in the context of such a problem. Not suggesting your question is unclear, inappropriate or unanswerable

Comment: Thank you very much Ruben. I will have to read more from existing answers in order to get an idea. :-) Appreciate your timely response.